# Splitting a list in Pandas Dataframe to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like shown below where the coordinates column contains X and Y coordinates:

```
    Coordinates Cluster
0   [25, 79]    2
1   [34, 51]    2
2   [22, 53]    2
3   [27, 78]    2
4   [33, 59]    2
```

I want to split the Coordinates column into X and Y column so that I have something like below:

```
    X   Y   Cluster
0   25  79  2
1   34  51  2
2   22  53  2
3   27  78  2
4   33  59  2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Coordinates').tolist(), index=df.index, columns=["X", "Y"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. Currently, it changes the name of the columns to 0 and 1, how can create those columns with specific names, e.g., X and Y?

Comment: I guess, I figured that out myself. Here is what I did  `out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Coordinates').tolist(), index=df.index, columns=["X", "Y"]))`

Comment: @RaziIqbal you got it ~

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Coordinates.str.split(',',1).tolist(),
                                 columns = ['X','Y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dump it into numpy as well :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "Coordinates": [[25, 79], [34, 51], [22, 53], [27, 78], [33, 59]],
    "Cluster": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
})


box = df.to_numpy()

pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([np.vstack(box[:, 0]), box[:, -1]]),
            columns=["X", "Y", "Cluster"])


    X   Y   Cluster
0   25  79  2
1   34  51  2
2   22  53  2
3   27  78  2
4   33  59  2
```